# DS18B20 no longer working

Tags: temperature, ds18b20, pi-b+

I had two of these running fine, but now they've stopped. From reading I've done I think this has something to do with kernel updates and device tree. There seems to be about half a dozen options now with numerous permutations of config, but I haven't got it working at all.

I have a **Pi B+** and I've wired:

- 4.7kΩ Resistor between pin 1 (3.3V) and pin 7 (GPIO 4)
- pin 1 (3.3V) to the +ve of the DS18B20
- pin 6 (GND) to the ground of the DS18B20
- pin 7 (GPIO 4) to the data of the DS18B20

I am running updated Raspian `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT`

From what I've read the options are:

- modules, and possibly parameters, in `/etc/modules`
- blacklist statements in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi.blacklist.conf`
- `device_tree=` or not in `/boot/config.txt`, and if not, then `dtoverlay` statement that includes

  - `w1-gpio-pullup` or `w1-gpio`
  - `gpiopin=X` where `X` is usually 4
  - `extpullup=Y` or ommitted where `Y` is a pin number?

**The device(s) is(are) never listed under `/sys/bus/w1/devices/` where they used to be. I mostly just have `w1_bus_master/` in there.**

Things I've tried:

### 1. Without Device Tree (attempting to go to original config)

`device_tree=` in `/boot/config.txt`.

`/etc/modules` including:

```
w1-gpio
w1-therm
```

This was an attempt to revert to the settings that worked before.

### 2. Without Device Tree but with more module params

`device_tree=` in `/boot/config.txt`.

`/etc/modules` including:

```
w1-gpio pullup=0 gpiopin=4 extpullup=1
w1-therm strong_pullup=1
```

### 3. With Device Tree (hay, it's obviously the cool thing to do)

`/boot/config.txt` contains: `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4`

I've also tried various combinations of blacklisting and listing in `/etc/modules` the `wp-gpio` and `wp-therm` modules.

### Things I've read that have only muddied my understanding(!)

Not least because I have a **Pi B+** whereas many are working with Pi2 which I don't have.

- [Kernel 3.18.8 breaks 1-wire](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=105315)
- [DS1820 no dir in w1/devices](http://forum.pimatic.org/topic/55/solved-ds1820-no-dir-in-w1-devices)
- Other rpi.se questions [1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26623/ds18b20-not-listed-in-sys-bus-w1-devices) [2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28336/24597) [3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/ds18b20-sensor-not-detecting)

### [EDIT] As suggested in comment:

- `/etc/modules` empty.
- `/boot/config.txt` does **not** have `device_tree=`, thus enabling device tree. It does not contain any `w1-*` lines at all.

Result: `lsmod` shows that neither `w1-gpio` nor `w1-therm` are there (nor `wire` which is usually there when the other two are).

After `sudo modprobe w1-gpio; sudo modprobe w1-therm` there is still nothing in `/sys/bus/w1/devices/`, not even the `w1_bus_master` one.

...

And with `dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4` in `/boot/config.txt`...reboot...

Now `lsmod` shows `wire` and `w1_gpio` **and** `w1_therm`. `ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/` has the devices! Thanks @Joan!

Comment: Use device tree.  I'm not sure if it is compulsory yet, it will be one day.  /etc/modules should not have 1-wire modules mentioned.  From memory device tree should load w1-gpio and w1-therm (use lsmod to check).  Could you ensure you are using device tree and an empty /etc/modules and reboot.

Comment: Thanks @joan I've edited question with the result of that.

Comment: The same with dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4 in /boot/config.txt.

Comment: @joan yes! The winning combination! Thanks so much.

Comment: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/348 also has some lengthy explanations on parasite mode. Its all confusing, indeed

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting this as it's the answer I got to but all credit is due to the commenter @Joan!

```
/etc/modules empty.
/boot/config.txt does not have device_tree=, thus enabling device tree. It does not contain any w1-* lines at all.
```

Result: lsmod shows that neither w1-gpio nor w1-therm are there (nor wire which is usually there when the other two are).

After sudo modprobe w1-gpio; sudo modprobe w1-therm there is still nothing in /sys/bus/w1/devices/, not even the w1_bus_master one.

...

And with dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4 in /boot/config.txt...reboot...

Now lsmod shows wire and w1_gpio and w1_therm. ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/ has the devices! Thanks @Joan!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

To enable 1-wire run

```
raspi-config
```

and go to `Interfacing Options -> 1-Wire`

(This will add `dtoverlay=w1–gpio` at the end of `/boot/config.txt`. Default pin is GPIO 4. If you would like to use a custom pin you have to manually change this line to `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=x` where x is other GPIO pin number)

Reboot the Pi

To list all devices that Raspberry Pi has discovered via 1-Wire busses which will be in the format "28-XXXXXXXXXXXX" run

```
ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/
```

To get temperature run

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/<your_device_id>/w1_slave
```