# 1-wire device not detected

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, sensor, 1-wire

I'm having trouble getting a 1-wire sensor to be detected on my Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+. The sensor is [this temperature and humidity sensor](http://aosong.com/en/products-51.html).

I have wired the red wire to 3.3V, the black wire to ground and the yellow wire to `GPIO4` (physical pin 7). I have also connected a 4.7k resistor from 3.3V to `GPIO4`.

I have enabled 1-wire in raspi-config, and my /boot/config.txt has the `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` line enabled (uncommented).

The kernel modules seem to be loaded correctly:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod | grep w1
w1_gpio                16384  0
wire                   45056  1 w1_gpio
```

I'm running Raspbian 9 (Stretch) and my kernel version is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

My pin configuration is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpio readall

 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B+-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 1 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B+-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

However, no devices get detected:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices $ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jul  8 13:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Jul  8 13:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  8 13:23 w1_bus_master1 -> ../../../devices/w1_bus_master1

pi@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1 $ cat w1_master_slaves
not found.
```

I have scoped the line on `GPIO4` and I do get the initial low going pulse followed by data, as expected :

[image: GPIO4 line]

Does anyone have any idea what I can try next? Or what might be going wrong?

Comment: I read that 1-Wrie drivers for old raspbian versions often won't work for new versions.  You might like to read my answers of the following questions for more details: (1) ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/raspberry-pi-3b-do-not-detect-ds18b20-on-1wire ),

(2) ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/pi-cant-find-5th-ds18b20/100244#100244 )

Comment: The link you listed is remarkably short of technical detail. The commonly used AOsong devices are NOT 1-wire and I see no code (working or otherwise).

Comment: I don't see any link to the sensor's datasheet, but my guess would be it's not a 1-wire sensor. Did you try a compatible one, e.g. DS18B20 ?

Comment: @Edrean Ernst, Asolong AM2105/2302 1-Wire is unique, for AsoLong/AsAir DHT11, DHT22, AM2302, AM2105: 

(1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/dht11-sensor-and-the-wrong-voltage-may-have-fried-my-rpi3

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97949/circuit-wiring-issue

(3) https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf

(4) https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1906201608_Aosong-Guangzhou-Elec-AM2105A_C394878.pdf

(5) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&hilit=DHT11&start=350#p1355567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that is a 1-wire (Dallas) bus device.

If it's manufactured by Aosong it's much more likely to use their one wire protocol (as used in their DHTxx series of temperature and humidity sensors).

The Chinese [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1906201608_Aosong-Guangzhou-Elec-AM2105A_C394878.pdf) confirms it uses the 40-bit Aosong one wire format (you can cut&paste the Chinese glyphs into Google translate).

Either disable the 1-wire bus on GPIO 4 or connect the device data pin (and pull-up to 3V3) to a different GPIO.

Then run some DHTxx software on that GPIO.

I would suggest you try my software which auto detects the common types of DHTxx.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD

TO BUILD

```
gcc -Wall -pthread -o DHTXXD test_DHTXXD.c DHTXXD.c -lpigpiod_if2
```

TO RUN

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

./DHTXXD -g17 # one reading from DHT connected to GPIO 17

./DHTXXD -g14 -i3 # read DHT connected to GPIO 14 every 3 seconds
```

Comment: I assumed 1-wire is 1-wire. It is not the Dallas 1-wire protocol and reading it as a DHT22 worked perfectly.

Comment: 1-Wire is 1-Wire.  It is a Dallas trademarked protocol.  However there are several one wire protocols.  Misleading advertising by Aosong.

Comment: Ah, it’s clear to me now. Thanks! For some reason I assumed the protocol is always standard on the 1-wire system. It’s like assuming the protocol over ethernet will always be http.