# The w1 folder is not showing up even after enabling the the 1 wire interface

Tags: raspi-config, 1-wire

The /sys/bus folder does not contain any folder named w1 even after enabling it through raspi-config or config.txt. This happened after I updated the raspi. I cant find any solution from the different forums.

Comment: ds18b20 driver installed?

Comment: How to install it?

Comment: search ***this*** forum: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/raspberry-pi-3b-do-not-detect-ds18b20-on-1wire/98434#98434

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 3b+ do not detect DS18b20 on 1Wire](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/raspberry-pi-3b-do-not-detect-ds18b20-on-1wire)