# Raspberry Pi B won't recognise DS18B20 sensor

Tags: gpio, pi-2, temperature, ds18b20

I have wired up my Raspberry Pi (RPI-0007) to the pins as outlined by http://www.modmypi.com/blog/ds18b20-one-wire-digital-temperature-sensor-and-the-raspberry-pi. However, when I change directory to `/sys/bus/w1/devices` nothing is there.

I have added `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4` to the boot config file (`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`) and rebooted but nothing is working. I have checked the wires, loaded the modules and checked the sensor is receiving power (using an LED on the breadboard). Note I have also tested the sensor on an arduino and it works perfectly - so the issue lies with the pi.

[image: This shows the white wire going to the 3v3 pin and the yellow wire going to gpio4]

[image: This shows the black wire going from ground to the ground rail on the breadboard, the other end of the white wire going to the positive rail on the bread board and the red wire taking the power to Pin Three on the sensor]

[image: This shows the wiring for the sensor. The red wire carries power to Pin three, the blue wire grounds the sensor and there is a 4.7kohm resistor going from Pin Two to the yellow wire that finishes at GPIO4]

The first picture shows the white wire going to the 3v3 pin and the yellow wire going to gpio4

The second picture  shows the black wire going from ground to the ground rail on the breadboard, the other end of the white wire going to the positive rail on the bread board and the red wire taking the power to Pin Three on the sensor.

The third picture shows the wiring for the sensor. The red wire carries power to Pin three, the blue wire grounds the sensor and there is a 4.7kohm resistor going from Pin Two to the yellow wire that finishes at GPIO4.

```
uname -a: Linux raspberry 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv71 GNU/Linux
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Altered boot config file to read `dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4`  as per http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/ds18b20-sensor-not-detecting and still no change

Comment: and turning off device tree doesn't make any difference

Comment: Could you use `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4` in /boot/config.txt and then reboot.  Note, this is different to what you said you used.  Then include the following information in your question.  Output of uname -a.  Output of cat /etc/os-release.  Output of lsmod.

Comment: shall I use that in addition to having device tree off or instead of? Will include information now.

Comment: You should be using device tree.  dtoverlay (device tree overlay) has no meaning otherwise.

Comment: You are using a fairly ancient kernel (in Pi terms).  However device tree should work.  Against that w1-therm and w1-gpio are not listed.  Could you `sudo modprobe w1-gpio` and `sudo modprobe w1-therm`.

Comment: I have redone those commands, unfortunately still not appearing in the w1 devices

Comment: I realised in the above I have not wired the pullup resistor correctly, I have rewired according to: http://www.reuk.co.uk/DS18B20-Temperature-Sensor-with-Raspberry-Pi.htm. However still no difference as no devices found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33620/discussion-between-paulbarr-and-joan).

Answer (score 2):

There are three minimum things to check here:

1. Which mode is the DS18B20, and whether the connections are done
   accordingly?
   If it is a parasitic mode sensor or normal sensor.
   Typically, the DS18B20 has to be wired as below:

   - (-) ve to GND
   - (+) ve to 3V3
   - S to GPIO.7 (Pin 7)
2. Configuration.

In /boot/config.txt,
add `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` at the end.

For this run `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`
 and then add `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` in the nano text editor. Click Y to save file while exiting.

Run `sudo reboot` to reboot the Pi.

3. Setting it all up
   You should setup it all next.

Run the following code in terminal:

`sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe q1-therm`

And now check
ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/

It should show up.

Comment: Do check @scherzkrapferl's answer below as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dr. Viper mentioned in his answer, you probably forgot to

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
```

To make this work by startup you can edit the `/etc/modules` by typing

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

into your terminal and add following lines:

```
w1-gpio
w1-term
```

To save this configuration with nano press `CTRL+O` to save the file and `CTRL+X` to exit nano.
After a reboot the changes should take affect and your temperature-sensor should be shown.

Comment: You may want to replace `STRG` with `CTRL` as the majority of potential readers will not understand otherwise.

Comment: `sudo modprobe q1-therm` should be `sudo modprobe w1-therm`