# PiTFT doesnot work after rpi-update

Tags: pitft, rpi-update

I updated the firmware with command :

```
sudo REPO_URI=https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware rpi-update
```

This install the kernel 3.18.5+

After reboot, the PiTFT is no more showing console as before (this is configured in /boot/cmdline.txt with `fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8`)

The `dmesg` command report an error related to the fbtft_device module :

> ```
> [   12.677434] fbtft_device:  SPI devices registered:
> [   12.692614] fbtft_device:  'fb' Platform devices registered:
> [   12.705285] fbtft_device:      bcm2708_fb id=-1 pdata? no
> [   12.713274] fbtft_device:  spi_busnum_to_master(0) returned NULL
> [   12.721724] fbtft_device: failed to register SPI device
> ```

Trying to insert (again) the module manually with the command

```
sudo modprobe -v fbtft_device debug=255
```

Reports :

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.5+/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft/fbtft_device.ko  name=pitft rotate=270 debug=255
ERROR: could not insert 'fbtft_device': Invalid argument
```

The problems seems links to SPI, but even if I insert `spi-bcm2708` module manually the result is the same.

How to insert (with this new kernel & firmware) the PiTFT module ?

==**UPDATE**==
I rollback to the previous release with

```
sudo REPO_URI=https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware rpi-update 4815829b3f98e1b9c2648d9643dfe993054923ce
```

And PiTFT works as before the update, then dmesg reports :

> ```
> [   12.758277] fbtft_device:  SPI devices registered:
> [   12.765007] fbtft_device:      spidev spi0.0 500kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
> [   12.776683] fbtft_device:      spidev spi0.1 500kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
> [   12.785487] fbtft_device:  'fb' Platform devices registered:
> [   12.793988] fbtft_device:      bcm2708_fb id=-1 pdata? no
> [   12.806073] fbtft_device: Deleting spi0.0
> [   12.818076] fbtft_device:  GPIOS used by 'pitft':
> [   12.824597] fbtft_device:    'dc' = GPIO25
> [   12.844709] fbtft_device:  SPI devices registered:
> [   12.856177] fbtft_device:      spidev spi0.1 500kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
> [   12.864281] fbtft_device:      fb_ili9340 spi0.0 32000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
> ```

Comment: According to the `insmod` output you are not using the new kernel, presumably because this isn't a pi 2.  The -v7 kernel will not run on anything else.

Comment: @goldilocks : it's a Pi B+ (CPU revision 0010), is this a Pi-2 ? The working kernel is `3.12.34+`, and the 'not' working kernel is `3.18.5+`.

Comment: May be a device tree problem. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f/27074#27074

Comment: @mpromonet no the B+ is not the same as the Pi 2. Pi 2 just recently came out. On my pi 2 (haven't ran rpi-update since yesterday) I'm on Linux 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l

Comment: The B+ and the **[Pi 2](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-2-on-sale/)** are not the same, no.  The latter just came out a few weeks ago and uses a quad core ARMv7 processor, which is why there is the new kernel for it.  That shouldn't be the cause of your problem though.  I'd have a look at the question joan pointed out.

Comment: @joan : you are right, Thanks for the link. The problem is fixed adding `dtparam=spi=on` in /boot/config.txt (or enable SPI through raspi-config).

Comment: If you found a solution, can you write it up as an answer for posterity?  You may have to wait 24 hours or something before you can tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the forum [I2C, SPI, I2S, LIRC, PPS, stopped working? Read this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=675658#p675658) and [FBTFT wiki](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki)

This could be done in 2 ways, modifying /boot/config.txt :

- Disabling device tree, enabling SPI and loading fbtft_device module using `sudo modprobe -v fbtft_device name=pitft rotate=270`

> device_tree=
>   dtparam=spi=on

- Enabling device tree and load pitft overlay (take care to not load fbtft_device module, it made the system hangs)

> dtoverlay=pitft,rotate=270

After reboot, the PiTFT display is back.

**UPDATE**
The FBTFT drivers are now in the linux kernel, then is works also with the  firmware coming from [Hexxeh](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware) using simply :

```
sudo rpi-update
```