# "Inappropriate ioctl for device" error since upgrading Rasbian & firmware

Tags: gpio, driver, spi

I was happily controlling [Shiftbrite LEDs](http://docs.macetech.com/doku.php/shiftbrite_2.0) using SPI and Python based on [this code](http://docs.macetech.com/doku.php/raspberry_pi_with_octobrite_shiftbrite)

Today I upgraded my Pi using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
```

Now my script no longer works. I get this error:

```
File "/home/pi/shiftbrite/go.py", line 81, in <module>
    fcntl.ioctl(spidev, 0x40046b04, array.array('L', [5000000]))
IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Might the value 0x40046b04 need to change since the upgrade? And I wonder if it was the upgrade to Raspbian or the Pi firmware that caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to re-enable SPI in raspi-config as described in [I2C, SPI, I2S, LIRC, PPS, stopped working? Read this.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=675658#p675658)

Funnily enough I was led to that post by this [previous answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f/27074#27074) by [Joan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan) - thanks Joan!

Answer (score 1):

The value 0x40046b04 is the value of macro SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ and there have been no changes there.

Are you sure spidev is an open descriptor for a SPI device?

---

The following code works on my Pi2.

Raspbian
3.18.8-v7+ #765 SMP PREEMPT

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import math
import array
import fcntl

spidev = file("/dev/spidev0.0", "wb")

rgb=bytearray(3)

#set the spi frequency to 20 kbps
fcntl.ioctl(spidev, 0x40046b04, array.array('L', [20000]))

while True :

   for i in range(0, 48):
      #use your own colors here
      rgb[0] = 1
      rgb[1] = 1
      rgb[2] = 1
      spidev.write(rgb)

   spidev.flush()
   time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Hi Joan. I have exactly the same Raspbian version, and your code gives me the same error I have been getting. I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "Are you sure spidev is an open descriptor for a SPI device?"

Comment: I just meant was spidev the result of opening a non SPI device, in which case the SPI specific IOCTL would be illegal.