# LIRC / Raspberry PI 2 , No input

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, lirc

I want to use LIRC with my new RPI 2. To do that, I followed [this](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/) tutorial. Basically it is telling me to do the following:

1. Add this to your /etc/modules file:

   ```
   lirc_dev lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=25 gpio_out_pin=22
   ```
2. Change your /etc/lirc/hardware.conf file to:

   ```
   ########################################################
   # /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
   #
   # Arguments which will be used when launching lircd LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"

   # Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
   # START_LIRCMD=false

   # Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
   # START_IREXEC=false

   # Try to load appropriate kernel modules LOAD_MODULES=true

   # Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers. DRIVER="default"
   # usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev DEVICE="/dev/lirc0" MODULES="lirc_rpi"

   # Default configuration files for your hardware if any LIRCD_CONF="" LIRCMD_CONF=""
   ########################################################
   ```
3. Edit your /boot/config.txt file and add:

   ```
   dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=25,gpio_out_pin=22
   ```

(I've done gpio_in_pin=25, because thats where I want the receiver to be ).

Another thing:
I don't have a three pin IR receiver, so I tried to make my own receiver (two pins) like this: One pin is coming from the PI's 5v, going to the collector of the transistor. Another one is coming from the GPIO 25, and the emitter.

But, when I run `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` and press a few buttons on the remote (2cm away from the sensor), I get nothing.

What is wrong ?
I have run rpi-update, apt-get upgrade and apt-get update also.

[image]

Comment: Does http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f/27074#27074 apply?

Comment: I've just seen your raspberrypi.org post.  It sounds like you have a bit of work to do on the IR receiver side.

Comment: @joan , I didnt understand your first question. Could you please tell me what to do in detail ?
as for the hardware, I tried connecting a RED LED to the output of the transistor, and the LED blinks as I press the buttons on my remote. I thought this meant the circuitry is fine. What do I do ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this was a very simple (and even dumber) one. It turns out that I was following the model B+'s pinout. The pin number 26 of raspberry pi 2 is somewhere else. I am posting the new pi's pinout here, just for future reference:

[image]

Comment: Remember to mark the question as answered if you have a solution.