# Unable to see Temp sensors at /sys/bus/w1/devices which was working until SD card got corrupted

Tags: python, raspbian-wheezy, ds18b20

I have several DS18B20 sensors wired to my Raspberry Pi and wrote a python script to read them all. I've had the script running for months without a problem. Last week I performed an update and an upgrade while my script was running and the pi crashed. The SD card was corrupted and I had to build a new one and now I do not see any of the devices at `/sys/bus/w1/devices`. When I type `ls` i get nothing, not even the `w1_bus_master1`

I have a Raspberry Pi **Model B, Revision 2.0, RAM 512 MB, Maker Sony**. I am running **Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux**. I double checked my wiring to make sure that there are no shorts or opens. I even got a new sensor and wired it to the pi by itself with same result. Could I have fouled something up while performing the update & upgrade while the script was running? Is there a way to test the GPIO port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Firmware 3.18.x includes a configuration change to enable Device Tree support by default which caused my problem. Take a look at the read me file here `/boot/overlays/readme.`
Rather than post the entire file here, here's [a link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/400dbb7c65eb25b7c43000b36fadb4312c26d1e0/boot/overlays/README).

I added `device_tree=`  in the `/boot/config.txt` file as noted in the above link since 
I was unable to read the `w1-gpio-overlay.dtb` file as mentioned on `line 207` of the readme file as that file appears to be a binary file.

Comment: Adding device_tree= will only be temporary reprieve.  At some stage device tree will be compulsory.  I'm surprised the answer I gave did not work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I did try the recommend fix but I couldn't figure out how to read the overlays binary file. Perhaps I'll post a new question to see if anyone knows how to the file.

Comment: You shouldn't need to touch any binary files.  You just add dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4 to /boot/config.txt.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it and it works. Wish I had voting privileges for you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like that you have upgraded to firmware which uses device tree.  If you were not using device tree before see [Firmware 3.18.x breaks I²C, SPI, audio, lirc, 1-wire (e.g. /dev/i2c-1, No such file or directory)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f/27074#27074)

See http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#GPIO for my method of testing the gpios.

With nothing CONNECTED to the gpios it tests that they can be read, written, and that the internal pull-ups and pull-downs are functional.