# I2C not working as expected

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c

I'm running a Pi B+ rev 1.2 and recently acquired 2 I2C modules:

DS-RGBW.S LED lighting
[image: DS-RGBW.S LED lighting picture]

Microstack accelerometer:
[image: Microstack accelerometer]

When connecting the LED module, address 70 appears to be occupied as planned. I modify the script to use `SMBus(1)` instead of `SMBus(0)`. Script runs, but no response. When terminating the script, python claims to have been at line 96, `time.sleep(000.1)`. None of the lights have been on. The 48VDC terminal is not used, but I'm not sure it's even supposed to be used. Attached to pin 3/4/5/6 as shown on the diagram given by the supplier.

So, ok. It might be from a bad batch, so I hooked up the accelerometer. I don't have the baseboard, but it fits just fine without (on pin 1/3/5/7/9/11)(leaving the 4+2 pins not connected). But now I `i2cdetect -y 1` shows an empty address table.

Yes, I did reboot after installing all required dependencies and yes all required configurations have been modified. I'm running the latest software on the latest Raspbian. How should I debug my I2C trouble? Anyone experience with problems like these?

If any pertinent information is missing, please comment.

#### Update:

Script called is from [this zip file](http://www.designersystems.co.uk/download/RGBW.S_Disk.zip) as stated in the product manual.
/RGBW.S_Disk/R-PI/RGBW.py

```
# Designer Systems DS-RGBW LED Lighting Shield Raspberry-PI Demonstrator

# Requires Raspberry-PI A or B board

# DS-RGBW.S [A0 & A1 jumpers ON] connected to I2C interface (GPIO pin 3 SDA, pin 5 SCL)

# RGBW.py   Date: 13/7/13   Version: 1.00 

# Run from LX terminal window using 'sudo python RGBW.py

# Fades WHITE up/down, outputs a number of RGB colours and then cycles through colour wheel

# Note: May require I2C setup procedure on R-PI

# Use CTRL+C to exit


# import modules needed for this application
import smbus
import time

# NOTE: THE ZERO IN THE COMMAND BELOW MAY NEED CHANGING TO A '1' DEPENDING ON THE RASPBERRY PI USED
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# Define DS-RGBW.S I2C address
address = 0x70

# Routine to write to I2c register from DS-RGBW.S
def writeRegister (register, value):
    bus.write_byte_data(address, register, value)

# Routine to write to I2c,define registers
def writeRGBWregisters (red, green, blue):
    bus.write_byte_data(address,3,red)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,4,green)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,5,blue)

# Routine to write to i2c, define registers
def writeHSBregister (hue,saturation,brightness):
    bus.write_byte_data(address,6,hue)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,7,saturation)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,8,brightness)

# Main program
while True:

# All off 
    bus.write_byte_data(address,2,0)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,3,0)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,4,0)
    bus.write_byte_data(address,5,0)

# Fade white LED from 0 to 99%   
for data in range(0,99):    
    writeRegister(2,data)
            time.sleep(0.01)

# Fade white LED from 99 to -1 
for data in range(99,-1,-1):    
    writeRegister(2,data)
            time.sleep(0.01)

# Sleep 2 second
    time.sleep(2)

# Send RGBW colour (Pink)      
    writeRGBWregisters(255,88,67)             

# Sleep 2 second
    time.sleep(2)

# Send RGBW colour (Green)
    writeRGBWregisters(48,187,80)      

# Sleep 2 seconds       
    time.sleep(2)

# Send RGBW colour (Orange)
    writeRGBWregisters(243,99,20)

# Sleep 2 second
    time.sleep(2)

# Send RGBW colour (Dark Purple)
    writeRGBWregisters(86,54,80)

# Sleep 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)

# Set colour wheel to start colour   
    writeHSBregister(0,255,255)

# Rotate though complete colour wheel by changing HSB Hue value     
    for hue in range(0,255):
           writeRegister(6,hue)
           time.sleep(000.1)

# Sleep 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)
```

### Update 2:

Re-flashed the RPi with a fresh install. It's still not working as expected, but now I get the following for `i2cdetect -y 1` with the RGBW connected:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
10: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ UU __ __ __ __
20: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
30: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ UU __ __ __ __
40: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
50: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
60: __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
70: 70 __ __ __ __ __ __ __
```

The `UU` weren't there before at `1b` and `3b`. They're also there when nothing is connected.

Comment: *"If any pertinent information is missing, please comment"* -> What script are you talking about?!?  All I see here are two photographs and some references to `i2cdetect`, which is a compiled executable.

Comment: @goldilocks Added.

Comment: did you add the i2c line in /boot/config.txt ? see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f

Comment: @TommyTrussell Yes, dtparam i2c_arm/i2c1/spi are all on.

Comment: OK I just got it working myself. You have to activate the i2c stuff in /boot/config.txt AND add the modules to /etc/modules

Comment: @TommyTrussell I'm not sure why, but that didn't do the trick for me. I might go for a fresh install to make sure I didn't mess something up in the meantime, but without any way to debug what exactly is wrong it's still stabbing in the dark.

Comment: [I guess I can't format in comments]   I was trying to show what I have in my /etc/modules

Comment: Yes I see the UUs sometimes, too -- it means the driver has detected a (potential) conflict at that spot and skipped probing it. The man page says "this strongly suggests there's a chip at this address." You do have one at address 70 -- is that where you expect it? If not, you may want to look for a driver conflict such as http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=81750 or http://jeelabs.org/book/1452c/

Comment: Yes, 70 is as expected. There's no reason to assume the device uses more than that address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problems (and the UU's are not the accelerometer, they are there on mine too). I'd given up on this when persistence got the better of me and I came across this: https://github.com/microstack-IoT/python3-microstacknode/issues/1

You may be one of the lucky people that got one of the 'couple' of boards made without the connection between pin 2 and 3 on JP1.

[image: Missing connection.]

You need to bridge this connection (I stuck a bent staple in the holes, but soldering may be better)!

Comment: There's supposed to be a connection between JS2 and JS3? Firing up my soldering iron.

Comment: Try the bent staple first, to make sure it works for your board! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get my i2c device to work. I followed the hints in [Firmware 3.18.x breaks I2C, SPI, audio, lirc, 1-wire (e.g. /dev/i2c-1, No such file or directory)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f)

Here's my /etc/modules

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

snd-bcm2835
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2708
```

(The snd-bcm2835 module was already in my /etc/modules file.)

As for /boot/config.txt for whatever reason the line added by raspi-config for i2c did NOT work so I commented it out.

```
$ cat /boot/config.txt     
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
```

Comment: I suspect at least one of the dtparam lines is superfluous (not needed) but I am not sure.

Comment: I can't imagine you need all of those indeed. However it should work, but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: You might try disconnecting all the add-on boards and seeing if the situation changes. I just tried it on mine, and the i2cdetect command still runs, it just doesn't show anything. ... never mind I just saw where you have already done that.

Comment: ALSO be sure you have run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade -- that's the first thing I did this morning.

Comment: It's the first thing I did when noticing it didn't work. I probably should've mentioned that somewhere, but I expected that to be superfluous.

Comment: after tinkering some more I have determined that for my i2c device (a PiFace LCD display board) I don't need all the lines so I am removing the dtparam=spi and dtparam=i2s lines from my example above. I am sorry it hasn't been helpful.

Comment: It's still not working, but see `update 2:` for the promised update.