# /dev/lirc0 does not exist

Tags: raspbian, lirc

I want to use an IR diod receiver. I installed lirc but when I write to terminal this code:

```
mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
```

it says

```
mode2: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
mode2: defauld_init(): No such file or directory
```

Where is the problem? Any idea?

Comment: It may be because of device tree.  See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f/27074#27074

Comment: thank you for your answer. It works, and I record my remote but now I'm writing "irw" but it doesn't show any thing about my buttons.

Comment: I think you should open a new question giving the details of the new problem.

Answer (score 6):

It means there is a configuration issue.

To fix it:

1. `sudo vim /boot/config.txt`
2. add `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=16` (**change the pin** to whatever you're using)
3. **reboot**

Comment: Reboot was key.

Comment: The tutorial I was following left this crucial step off.