# Firmware modules not available in Raspbian os

Tags: raspbian, i2c, modules, firmware, lirc

I am working on a project. I have Raspbian installed on my Raspberry Pi. When I do `sudo lsmod` I have no output. I cannot use lirc and i2c module as this require firmware modules. I have to submit the project in 5 days.

Here is the output of `lsmod`:

```
Module Size Used by
```

For `modeprobe i2c_dev`:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep:
could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.18.9+/modules.dep.bin'.
```

`sudo i2cdetect -y 1` gives this output:

```
Could not open file '/dev/i2c-1' or '/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.9+ #767 PREEMPT Sat Mar 7 21:41:13 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

`cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Welcome -- but you are not going to get any help unless you can explain further **what your problem is.**  There should not be an issue *loading* the i2c modules on Raspbian.  What happens if you try `sudo modprobe i2c_dev` then `lsmod` (which does not require `sudo`)?  Also make sure you have [read this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27074/5538) if the issue is *using* the modules.

Comment: sorry about that. Here is the output of lsmod" Module                  Size  Used by". For modeprobe i2c_dev 
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.18.9+/modules.dep.bin'.    sudo i2cdetect -y 1  gives this output Could not open file '/dev/i2c-1' or '/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory

Comment: @user3563091 You need to add edit your original post and add any relevant information.  As a minimum I'd suggest the information in your comment, plus the model of Pi you are using, plus the result of uname -a, plus the result of cat /etc/os-release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep:
could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.18.9+/modules.dep.bin'.
```

It would seem that this directory is missing or something.  Have a look in `/lib/modules/3.18.9+` and see if there is anything there.  If there is, try `sudo depmod` and then `sudo modprobe i2c-dev` again.

If either of those fails, or that directory is missing or empty, you could try `rpi-update` and see if that will replace them.

If that fails, the easiest thing to do is probably just re-install your SD card image.  Alternately, you could copy that directory out of an image ([see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538) about how to get it out), if it is there (it might not be if it was part of an update).  It needs to be `3.18.9+` exactly.