# My Raspberry Pi doesn't detect i2c BMP085 slave

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c

My Raspy 2 B+ doesn't detect the BMP085 sensor via i2c bus.
The wiring was checked again and again, it's true :

Vcc -> 3.3V
GND -> GND 
SDA -> SDA0 pin
SCL -> SCL0 pin

**Results of the "i2cdetect" command when the BMP085 is connected :**
[image]

**Results of the "i2cdetect -y 0":**
[image]

i2c is already enabled and the BMP085 works perfectly on an Arduino Uno !

**Kernel Version :**

*Linux raspberrypi 4.4.11+ #888 Mon May 23 20:02:58 BST 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux*

**OS Version :**

*PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"*

**The blacklisted file is empty. And I2C is already enabled with the "raspi-config" command.**

Raspy connections
[image]

BMP085 connections
[image]

Comment: You haven't connected the BMP085 to the Pi properly.  A photo of your connections may show what is wrong.

Comment: The photos are a little too blurred to make out the connections.

Comment: GND : Pin 6 (black), SDA : Pin 3/GPIO8 (Yellow), SCL : Pin 5/GPIO9 (Green), VCC : 3.3 V / Pin 1 (Red)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27074/33810) ... firmware might be the problem

Comment: I know this is silly, but try different jumper cables?

Comment: @recantha Thanks, but I've tried all ..

Comment: @shreyas-murali Thanks, It may be well a kernel version the problem !

Comment: Is it definitely a 3v3 module, not 5v?

Comment: @kennetrunner , It works in 3.3V with Arduino. The datasheet shows that the range is : 1.8 to 3.6VDC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your software is working fine.
check if you have pull ups on your slave device.
although it is master devices responsibility to provide pull ups. if you don't have pull-ups then install 4.7K pull-ups on SDA and SCL line. it should work. if you are not comfortable with hardware get a [raspberry pi i2c shield](https://www.controleverything.com/content/I2C-Master?sku=TOUTPI2).

Comment: On the Pi the slave device **SHOULD NOT** provide pull-ups.  The Pi has hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 on I2C bus 1 (pins 3/5).  Slave pull-ups can damage the Pi, especially if they are to a voltage greater than 3V3.

Comment: @joan i am really really sorry. yes, you are correct its master responsibility to provide pulls.. i just got confused .. my apologies...

Answer (score 0):

Usually posting the details of `uname -a` (kernel version) and `/etc/os-release` (os version) helps in narrowing down problems.

I suspect the i2c has been blacklisted (disabled) in the kernel. 
[here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c) are the instructions to enable it.
briefly using `raspi-config` you should be able to enable like so

`sudo raspi-config`
`=> Advanced Options`
`=> I2C`
`Enable ? Yes`

Reboot and check again.

Comment: The I2C bus 1 is working and present.  Otherwise i2cdetect would fail as it does for bus 0.